# Better way to say "my curiosity for how things work"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am trying to describe my curiosity for how "things" work. IE - I am curious to know how a car works, but a more broader statement for how things work.

Can anyone help me think of a more elegant way of saying that statement?

Answer (score 0):

'Learn' is probably a better word choice for things you do not yet know. Perhaps:

> I am curious to learn how cars and other things work.